# A TV show in which a victim is convinced about a zombie apocalypse for many days

Tags: story-identification, tv, zombie, apocalypse

Looking for a TV show I had seen around 7 years ago.

It's a show in which a family comes up to the TV Host and tells them that their son is very lazy and they wish to fix it.

So the TV crew set up this enormous TV set, and fool the victim into thinking that the world is hit by a zombie virus and everyone he knows is gone. He even meets other people (TV crew) who rescue him. This prank goes on for days, and the victim is under constant surveillance.

I remember just one episode of the show. I'm sure there are other themes too.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be on-topic given it's not actually about science fiction except in a sort of meta way. There may be science fictional details, if there are I suggest you include them

Comment: There was also a spoof big brother series 'Dead Set' which was a big brother/Zombie apocalypse crossover.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [*Derren Brown: Apocalypse*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2513228/)

This is a two part TV series from 2012 initially shown on Channel 4, the IMDB description is as follows:

> A member of the public is given a second chance at life when mentalist Derren Brown makes him realize how important life is by tricking him into believing that a meteor has hit the earth and is now populated by zombies.

You can actually watch this online on Derren's verified YouTube channel:

- [Part One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_CUrMJOxqs)
- [Part Two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lgvk1pj_Eto)